# Given a simple logit panel data model, the MLE estimators are inconsistent

Tags: mathematical-statistics, econometrics, panel-data, logit, consistency

Consider a binary choice model, $P \left( y _ { i t } = 1 | x _ { i t } , \alpha _ { i } \right) = F \left( x _ { i t } \beta _ { 0 } + \alpha _ { i } \right)$, $$F ( z ) = \frac { e ^ { z } } { 1 + e ^ { z } }$$, we assume $T = 2 \text { with } x _ { i 1 } = 0 \text { and } x _ { i 2 } = 1$.
Why the MLE $\hat{\beta}$ for $\beta_0$ is converging in probability to $2\beta_0$.
I tried to write out the log-likelihood function :  $$l \left( \beta , \alpha _ { i } \right) = \sum _ { i } \sum _ { t } y _ { i t } \log \left( F \left( x _ { i t } \beta _ { 0 } + \alpha _ { i } \right) \right) + \left( 1 - y _ { i t } \right) \log \left( 1 - F \left( x _ { i t } \beta _ { 0 } + \alpha _ { i } \right) \right)$$
And FOC:
$\begin{aligned} \frac { \delta l } { \delta \alpha _ { i } } & = y _ { i 1 } + y _ { i 2 } - \frac { e ^ { \alpha _ { i } } } { 1 + e ^ { \alpha _ { i } } } - \frac { e ^ { \beta _ { 0 } + \alpha _ { i } } } { 1 + e ^ { \beta _ { 0 } + \alpha _ { i } } } = 0 \\ \frac { \delta l } { \delta \beta _ { 0 } } & = \sum _ { i } y _ { i 2 } - \frac { e ^ { \beta _ { 0 } + \alpha _ { i } } } { 1 + e ^ { \beta _ { 0 } + \alpha _ { i } } } = 0 \end{aligned}$

Then I get stuck here. Because the first FOC may not hold when $y _ { i 1 } + y _ { i 2 } =$2 or 0. Does making the Hessian matrix help here? And I need some help to prove $\hat{\beta}\xrightarrow{p} 2\beta_0$